# Screen capture TextureView is black using DrawingCache

Tags: android, screen-capture, textureview

I have a custom tiling view, which was until recently based on a SurfaceView. I have now changed it to extend TextureView.

Basically I am getting a large image in tile bits.

I need to capture all the content of the screen and save it as a bitmap, which has worked with all views including the SurfaceView. However, when i use the same method now, the area of the TextureView is black. I have read that this has something to do with HW acceleration.

Is there any way of capturing the image of the texture view?
Below is the screen capture method.

```
public File takeScreenShot(View contentView)
{
    File result = null;

    String mPath = this.cacheDir + "/screenshot.png";
    File imageFile = new File(mPath);
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        imageFile.delete();
        Log.i("ImageManager","Old screenshot image was deleted");
    }

    // create bitmap screen capture
    Bitmap bitmap;
    View v1 = contentView;
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    v1.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        result = imageFile;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: New attempt
Get all TextureViews and call getBitmap. This works, however placing them on top of the larger bitmap does not look right with the coordinates from the TilingView it self or the getLocation OnScreen() or getLocationInWindow().

```
public List<TilingTextureView> getAllTextureViews(View view)
{
    List<TilingTextureView> tilingViews = new ArrayList<TilingTextureView>();
    if (view instanceof TilingTextureView) {
        tilingViews.add((TilingTextureView)view);
    }
    else if(view instanceof ViewGroup)
    {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            tilingViews.addAll(getAllTextureViews(viewGroup.getChildAt(i)));
        }
    }
return tilingViews;
}
```

This bit is added in the takeScreenShot method after getting the screen shot of the entire view.

```
List<TilingTextureView> tilingViews = getAllTextureViews(contentView);
if (tilingViews.size() > 0) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    for (TilingTextureView tilingTextureView : tilingViews) {
        Bitmap b = tilingTextureView.getBitmap(tilingTextureView.getWidth(), tilingTextureView.getHeight());
        int[] location = new int[2];
        tilingTextureView.getLocationInWindow(location);
        int[] location2 = new int[2];
        tilingTextureView.getLocationOnScreen(location2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, location[0], location[1], null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually worked. I just had to correct the images according to the parent view in relation to the screen location.

Comment: if you solve your problem, post the solution in answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Some thing to notice:

```
Bitmap textureViewBitmap = textureView.getBitmap();

View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
v1.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
viewBitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(textureViewBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(viewBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFileDest);
int quality = 100;
cameraBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Assume the textureView is fullscreen and only one. If you would like the overlay view covered the TextureView, `viewBitmap.setHasAlpha(true);` is important, otherwise the combined bitmap is still black on the "textureView part".